# roslyn script getting error adding methods/functions

Tags: c#, exception, roslyn, .net-4.6

I developed a method to test if a script have bugs:

```
    public static object Test(string code, string references)
    {
        try
        {
            Compilation compilation = CSharpScript.Create(code,
                options: ScriptOptions.Default
                    .AddReferences(references)
                    .AddImports("System.Collections.Specialized", "System.Linq", "System.Net"),
                    globalsType: typeof(ScriptObject)
            ).GetCompilation();
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                EmitResult result = compilation.Emit(ms);

                if (!result.Success)
                {
                    var failures = result.Diagnostics.Where(diagnostic =>
                        diagnostic.IsWarningAsError ||
                        diagnostic.Severity == DiagnosticSeverity.Error).Select(s => s.GetMessage());

                    return (new { Success = false, ErrorMessage = failures });
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return (new { Success = false, ErrorMessage = e.Message });
        }
        return (new { Success = true });
    }
```

If I ran simple code the test pass OK

But if I add to the code a method/function, I get an exception. Ex:

```
int Add(int x, int y) {
    return x+y;
};
Add(1, 4)
```

Taken from here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cdndevs/2015/12/01/adding-c-scripting-to-your-development-arsenal-part-1/

I get the error

> ; expected,Semicolon after method or accessor block is not valid,Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

The error is in the "return x+y;" sentence, if I add "int c = x + y;" I get the error on that line

It's expected to work, isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

As the error is trying to tell you, you can't put a semicolon after a method declaration.

You can see this clearly [here](http://tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net/#b:master/f:sr/JYOwLgBAggJjAUpIA8A0EkQJ4EoIG8AoCEiAJwFMwBXMkCZAaiwG5CBfN2BARnQBYchIA===)

Delete the semicolon and you'll be fine.